# mongo db error - end point working - data is not saved in database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

While checking an endpoint using POST method in postman, there is no error.

.env file with PORT, MONGO_URI and the mongoose connection is set up properly, and returning no error.

code in my app.js

```
const express = require('express')
require('./db/db')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

dotenv.config({ path: 'config.env' })
const PORT = process.env.PORT

const User = require('./model/user')

app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    res.send('Hello')
})

app.post('/create-user', async(req, res)=>{
    const user = await User({ 
        fullname: 'John5 Doe', 
        email:'john5@email.com', 
        password:'12345'
    });
    await user.save();
    res.json(user);
})

app.listen(PORT, () =>{
    console.log(`app is running on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

But the data is not saved in MongoDB database. As I check the endpoint in postman and refresh the collection in mongo db, it is showing this page.[image]

how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.post('/create-user', async(req, res)=>{
const user = new User({ 
    fullname: 'John5 Doe', 
    email:'john5@email.com', 
    password:'12345'
});
await user.save();
res.json(user); })
```

It should be new User not await User. Also you can use try catch block inside your function so that you will get to know the error logs.